# What is a Tower Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Tower Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

[image: Examples of Tower Words]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Tower Words™,Not Tower Words™
ANVIL,HAMMER
AX,SWORD
COOCOO,RAVEN
DRUG,COCAINE
FILET,BEEF
HUG,KISS
KUSSOS,WHAT
LEZ,PLEASE
PI,MATH
TILT,SLANT
US,ME
VILE,GOOD
WHY,NOT
XU,CHINA
ZEE,EASY
```

Comment: Hey, nice Homestuck avatar! :D

Comment: @Deusovi Agreed :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Tower Word™ is a word ...

> Consisting of letters which you can stack to form a tower. The edges of the letters that are stacked must be perfect (i.e, perfectly curved edges must be placed on top of perfectly curved edges and perfectly straight edges must be placed on top of perfectly straight edges).  Such as ANVIL, The edges of the bottom parts of A can be placed on top of the edges of N, similarly, the bottom edges of N can placed on top of V and so on.

Take the first three words as examples:

> [image]

Comment: COOCOO seems unstable but ok hahaha

Comment: So why is GOOD not a tower word as well? If COOCOO is stable, so should be GOOD

Comment: @Zibelas, I see it seems stable, but another condition is that the edges of both letters must be either both straight, curved, or straight with a curve. For example, COOCOO is stable as the edges of the Cs and Os are curved. GOOD is not as stable because the edge of O is totally curved while D is straight with a curve.

Comment: In that case a lot of words have a problem. I agree with ANVIL, but take TILT, the T is fitting on the I, how is the I fitting on the L? One is centered, one is left orientated.

Comment: @Zibelas I thought of this too, but it seems the horizontal alignment is not taken into account, this is like how Sean created the stacking of ANVIL.

Comment: Oh well, not enough test cases and nobody wats to be nitpicking :) Good job in solving it